# Firebase terminal warning recomending v10.6.0 but I have already installed v10.8.0

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I have a Vue JS app with Firebase. I was using Firebase v10.7.2 and when I checked for updates v10.8.0 was available, but when I did npm audit I get a warning that I have 10 low severity vulnerabilities all in the Firebase package.

```
undici  <=5.28.2
Undici proxy-authorization header not cleared on cross-origin redirect in fetch - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-3787-6prv-h9w3
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install firebase@10.6.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/undici
  @firebase/auth  >=1.5.0-20231112213030
  Depends on vulnerable versions of undici
  node_modules/@firebase/auth
    firebase  0.900.22 || 7.9.1-0 - 7.9.1-canary.0396117e || 8.10.0-20217172214 - 8.10.0-canary.f40c0db53 || 9.0.0-20217250818 - 9.0.0-canary.d0d3acb10 || 9.0.1-2021727231341 - 9.0.1-canary.e039e1472 || 9.0.2-2021891633 - 9.0.2-canary.ff9baf70c || 9.0.3-202181503543 - 9.1.0-canary.f7d8324a1 || 9.1.1-2021830195733 - 9.1.1-canary.e70de6201 || 9.1.2-20219523556 - 9.1.2-canary.fc1d36497 || 9.19.1-20230331192943 - 9.19.1-canary.264909862 || 9.22.1-20230524195328 || 10.5.2-20231027003707 - 10.5.2-canary.ff1a6ec2c || 10.6.0-20231107192534 - 10.6.0-canary.ebc694a33 || >=10.7.0-20231112213030
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/auth
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/auth-compat
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/firestore
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/firestore-compat
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/functions
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/functions-compat
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/storage
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/storage-compat
    node_modules/firebase
  @firebase/auth-compat  0.4.9-20231107192534 - 0.4.9-canary.a5c1a3594 || >=0.5.0-20231112213030
  Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/auth
  Depends on vulnerable versions of undici
  node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat
  @firebase/firestore  4.3.2-20231027003707 - 4.3.2-canary.ff1a6ec2c || >=4.4.0-20231112213030
  Depends on vulnerable versions of undici
  node_modules/@firebase/firestore
    @firebase/firestore-compat  <=0.0.900-exp.520ca39d0 || 0.3.21-20231027003707 - 0.3.21-canary.ff1a6ec2c || 0.3.22-20231107192534 - 0.3.22-canary.ebc694a33 || 0.3.23-20231112213030 - 0.3.25
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/firestore
    node_modules/@firebase/firestore-compat
  @firebase/functions  >=0.11.0-20231112213030
  Depends on vulnerable versions of undici
  node_modules/@firebase/functions
    @firebase/functions-compat  0.3.5-20230523183426 - 0.3.5-canary.0d29adc97 || >=0.3.6-20231112213030
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/functions
    node_modules/@firebase/functions-compat
  @firebase/storage  0.11.2-20230301000120 - 0.11.2-canary.2a2e2b7ce || 0.12.0-20231112213030 - 0.12.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of undici
  node_modules/@firebase/storage
    @firebase/storage-compat  <=0.0.900-exp.520ca39d0 || 0.1.4-202192711727 - 0.1.4-canary.f27fe4304 || 0.3.2-20230301000120 - 0.3.2-canary.2a2e2b7ce || >=0.3.3-20231112213030
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/storage
    node_modules/@firebase/storage-compat

10 low severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

So I updated to v10.8.0 expecting that that would remove the error as I guess I expect that the required changes in v10.6.0 would be included in v10.8.0. No luck the error remained. I ran npm audit fix --force and rolled back to 10.6.0 and the warning is no longer there. My question is, do I just stick with 10.6.0 and never update to 10.8.0 and beyond? That does not sound like a great idea, I need to keep all my libraries up to date right? I am keen to better understand what is happening here and what the best course of action is?

Comment: If you want to report a problem with the Firebase CLI, open an issue on its [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools).  We can't really tell you what you should be doing day-to-day with it.  Do whatever you're comfortable with and meets your needs.

Comment: [npm audit: Broken by Design](https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/)